# Azure Data Explorer converting guid-string in dynamic column to lower case

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

If I write json object into a column which is of data type dynamic, fields which match to guid format are converted to lower case automatically.

If I parse a string with `extractjson` I get the guid in upper case:

```
print('{"guid":"6F77A167-8B36-49BB-8846-497B7F1BE1BF"}')
| extend guid = extractjson("$.guid", print_0)

// result: 6F77A167-8B36-49BB-8846-497B7F1BE1BF
```

but in case of using type dynamic or `parse_json` the conversion to lower case happens:

```
print('{"guid":"6F77A167-8B36-49BB-8846-497B7F1BE1BF"}')
| extend guid = parse_json(print_0)

// result: {"guid":"6f77a167-8b36-49bb-8846-497b7f1be1bf"}

print('{"guid":"6F77A167-8B36-49BB-8846-497B7F1BE1BF"}')
| extend guid = todynamic(print_0)

// result: {"guid":"6f77a167-8b36-49bb-8846-497b7f1be1bf"}
```

Can somebody tell me if this is intended behaviour? From my point of view there is no need to convert guid to lower case by default, is there a drawback when keeping the case sensitivity?

In my case the system which is used relies on the case sensitive data (which I know isn't good design) and cannot change this short term.

Is there a way to use json objects (not only single field values) in ADX without getting all the guid converted to lower case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious, I think the problem is the difference in the return type between `extractjson` and the guid in any of the dynamic conversion functions.

I.E.

```
let test = '{"guid":"6F77A167-8B36-49BB-8846-497B7F1BE1BF"}';
let testDirect = dynamic({"guid":"6F77A167-8B36-49BB-8846-497B7F1BE1BF"});
print castDynamic=gettype(todynamic(test)["guid"]), gettype(Parse=parse_json(test)["guid"]), ToObject=gettype(toobject(test)["guid"]), Direct=gettype(testDirect["guid"])
```

Will show that all of the possible ways to convert result in 'guid' having type guid. But with

```
let test2 = '{"guid":"6F77A167-8B36-49BB-8846-497B7F1BE1BF"}';
print gettype(extractjson("$.guid", test2))
```

The return type of `extractjson` is a string. In fact, ignoring the dynamic, just taking in a string with the value of the guid and casting to guid will result in it "lower casing the string" (only kinda since the result is not a string but a guid).

```
let test3 = "6F77A167-8B36-49BB-8846-497B7F1BE1BF";
print toguid(test3)
```

Since there is no good way (that I am aware of) to force todynamic to choose types, I don't believe it is possible to force the upper case behavior. Your best bet that I can see is retroactively dealing with it by converting the value to a string and upper casing it yourself, or to somehow trick todynamic into not converting the value to a guid (i.e. appending a value inside the guid like string).

Comment: Good to know! Hopefully this is helpful for others then. Which did you go with? Casting and fixing, or pre-appending to the GUID before dynamic conversion?

Comment: we added a prefix to the string that contains the upper case guid which caused ADX to handle it as string in our dynamic column. Later we copy it to another column and remove the prefix `id = replace("_guid_", "", tostring(value.meta.id))`